# Type cast custom types to base types

Tags: go

How can I convert custom type to `interface{}` and then to base type (ex. `uint8`)?

I can't use direct cast like `uint16(val.(Year))` because I may not know all custom types, but I can determinate base types (`uint8`, `uint32`,...) in runtime

---

There are many custom types (usually used as enums) based on numeric:

ex:

```
type Year  uint16
type Day   uint8
type Month uint8
```

and so on...

The question is about type casting from `interface{}` to base types:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Year uint16

// ....
//Many others custom types based on uint8

func AsUint16(val interface{}) uint16 {
    return val.(uint16) //FAIL:  cannot convert val (type interface {}) to type uint16: need type assertion
}

func AsUint16_2(val interface{}) uint16 {
    return uint16(val) //FAIL:   cannot convert val (type interface {}) to type uint16: need type assertion
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(AsUint16_2(Year(2015)))
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/cyAnzQ90At

Comment: Please note that neither `val.(unit16)` nor `uint16(val)` is a "cast": The first is a "type assertion" and the second and "type conversion".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using the [`reflect`](https://godoc.org/reflect) package:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

type Year uint16

func AsUint16(val interface{}) uint16 {
    ref := reflect.ValueOf(val)
    if ref.Kind() != reflect.Uint16 {
        return 0
    }
    return uint16(ref.Uint())
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(AsUint16(Year(2015)))
}
```

Depending on your situation, you may want to return `(uint16, error)`, instead of returning the empty value.

https://play.golang.org/p/sYm1jTCMIf

Answer (score 9):

Why did you include `Year` in the question? Are you hoping to convert arbitrary things into Years, or convert Years into uint16s?

If I assume you meant the latter case, then it would be better to use a method

```
func (y Year) AsUint16() uint16 { 
    return uint16(y)
}
```

which doesn't need any type assertions or reflection.

https://play.golang.org/p/9wCQJe46PU

Comment: I have many (N) custom types based on simple types (uint8, 16, 32...). And I don't want create N methods instead of the one

Comment: That's fair, but it's worth weighing up the pros and cons of each approach. The explicit approach I described above is simple, fast and type-safe but possibly too verbose. The reflective approach will be slower and less explicit in what it does to people who come along and read your code.

Comment: FWIW, I've dealt with a similar situation by using [Gen](https://github.com/clipperhouse/gen) to create boilerplate code from templates, but in your case it's not a compelling choice.

Answer (score 0):

#### Go 1.18 and above

After the introduction of generics, it's now easier to write such a function that works for any defined type.

```
func AsUint16[T ~uint16](v T) uint16 {
     return uint16(v)
}

func AsUint8[T ~uint8](v T) uint8 {
     return uint8(v)
}
```

Unlike with `interface{}`, the conversion works because the type parameter is explicitly constrained to types with that specific underlying type using tilde `~` (more info: [What's the meaning of the new tilde token ~ in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70888240/whats-the-meaning-of-the-new-tilde-token-in-go)).

The downside is that you must write a different function for each underlying type, as shown above with `uint16`, `uint8`, etc. A union constraint would work with a type switch in the function body, but in my opinion it's much clearer to use specialized functions — the result is the same.