# What's the meaning of the new tilde token ~ in Go?

Tags: go, generics

Go introduces the new token `~`.

> ~T means the set of all types with underlying type T

However, I could not understand it, ask someone to help explain.

The following is an example.

```
type Ordered interface {
      Integer | Float | ~string
}
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In Go generics, the `~` tilde token is used in the form `~T` to denote the set of types whose underlying type is `T`.

It was also called "approximation" constraint element in the [generics proposal](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md#approximation-constraint-element), which explains what it's good for in plain language:

> Listing a single type is useless by itself. For constraint satisfaction, we want to be able to say not just int, but “any type whose underlying type is int”. [...] If a program uses `type MyString string`, the program can use the `<` operator with values of type `MyString`. It should be possible to instantiate [a function] with the type `MyString`.

If you want a formal reference, the language spec has placed the definition of *underlying types* in [its own section](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Underlying_types):

> Each type T has an underlying type: If T is one of the predeclared boolean, numeric, or string types, or a type literal, the corresponding underlying type is T itself. Otherwise, T's underlying type is the underlying type of the type **to which T refers in its type declaration**.

This covers the very common cases of type literals and other composite types with bound identifiers, or types you define over predeclared identifiers, which is the case mentioned in the generics proposal:

```
// underlying type = struct literal -> itself -> struct { n int }
type Foo struct {
    n int
}

// underlying type = slice literal -> itself -> []byte
type ByteSlice []byte

// underlying type = predeclared -> itself -> int8
type MyInt8 int8

// underlying type = predeclared -> itself -> string
type MyString string
```

The practical implication is that an interface constraint whose type set has only exact elements doesn't allow your own defined types:

```
// hypothetical constraint without approximation elements
type ExactSigned interface {
    int | int8 | int16 | int32 | int64
}

// CANNOT instantiate with MyInt8
func echoExact[T ExactSigned](t T) T { return t }

// constraints.Signed uses approximation elements e.g. ~int8
// CAN instantiate with MyInt8
func echo[T constraints.Signed](t T) T { return t }
```

As with other constraint elements, you can use the approximation elements in unions, as in [`constraints.Signed`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/constraints#Signed) or in anonymous constraints with or without syntactic sugar. Notably the syntactic sugar with only one approx element is valid:

```
// anonymous constraint
func echoFixedSize[T interface { ~int8 | ~int32 | ~int64 }](t T) T { 
    return t 
}

// anonymous constraint with syntactic sugar
func echoFixedSizeSugar[T ~int8 | ~int32 | ~int64](t T) T { 
    return t 
}

// anonymous constraint with syntactic sugar and one element
func echoFixedSizeSugarOne[T ~int8](t T) T { 
    return t 
}
```

As anticipated above, a common use case for approximation elements is with composite types (slices, structs, etc.) that need to have methods. In that case you must bind the identifier:

```
// must bind identifier in order to declare methods
type ByteSeq []byte

func (b ByteSeq) DoSomething() {}
```

and now the approximation element is handy to allow instantiation with `ByteSeq`:

```
// ByteSeq not allowed, or must convert func argument first
func foobar[T interface { []byte }](t T) { /* ... */ }


// ByteSeq allowed
func bazquux[T interface { ~[]byte }](t T) { /* ... */ }

func main() {
    b := []byte{0x00, 0x01}
    seq := ByteSeq{0x02, 0x03}

    foobar(b)           // ok
    foobar(seq)         // compiler error
    foobar([]byte(seq)) // ok, allows inference
    foobar[[]byte](seq) // ok, explicit instantiation, then can assign seq to argument type []byte

    bazquux(b)          // ok
    bazquux(seq)        // ok
}
```

**NOTE**: you can not use the approximation token with a type parameter:

```
// INVALID!
type AnyApprox[T any] interface {
    ~T
}
```

Answer (score 10):

There is not just the new token, but the new syntax for interfaces. You can declare an interface with type constraints in addition to method constraints.

To satisfy an interface, the type must satisfy both the method constraints and the type constraints.

From the [docs](https://tip.golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types):

> An interface representing all types with underlying type int which implement the String method.
>
> ```golang
> interface {
>   ~int
>   String() string
> }
> ```

For a type to have an "underlying type" of `int`, that means the type takes the following form:

```golang
type SomeType int
```

And to satisfy the method constraint, there must be declared a method with the specified signature:

```golang
func (v SomeType) String() string {
  return fmt.Sprintf("%d", v)
}
```

Answer (score -4):

## Tidle Token - The Main Difference

```golang
type Numeric interface {
    ~int | ~int32 | ~int64 | ~float32 | ~float64 | ~uint | ~uint8 | ~uint16 | ~uint32 | ~uint64
}


type Numeric interface {
    int | int32 | int64 | float32 | float64 | uint | uint8 | uint16 | uint32 | uint64
 }
```

The main difference between these two Numeric interface types is:

The first one uses the tilde ~ to indicate the numeric types it includes, while the second one just lists the types directly without the ~.

The tilde in Go indicates the underlying type, so ~int means specifically the int type, not int8/16/32/64.

So the first Numeric interface is more strict and only includes the exact int, int32, etc types as defined in Go.

The second Numeric interface is more broad and includes any int or uint types, including int8, uint16, etc.

### In summary:

- The first only includes the specific types listed.
- The second includes those types plus any aliases like int8, float32, etc.

So the second Numeric interface is compatible with more numeric types overall.

In my opinion, I would recommend using `~` to make it more strict and better to work with