# How to convert `type Int32 int32` to `int32`?

Tags: go, generics

We have the following code that's generated (so we can't change it to `type Enum interface { int32 }`):

```golang
type Enum int32
```

There are a bunch of these type definitions to `int32`.

I'm trying to create a generic function that can convert a slice of such type definitions to a `[]int32`:

```golang
func ConvertToInt32Slice[T int32](ts []T) []int32 {
    return lo.Map(ts, func(t T, _ int) int32 {
        return int32(t)
    })
}
```

but the following complains with `Type does not implement constraint 'interface{ int32 }' because type is not included in type set ('int32')`:

```
type Int32 int32
var int32s []Int32
i32s := ConvertToInt32Slice(int32s)
```

What's needed to implement the generic function so it can be used as intended?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want a generic function that operates on all types that have the *underlying type* `int32`. That's what the tilde (`~`) token is for.
You should change the signature of your function to:

```
func ConvertToInt32Slice[T ~int32](ts []T) []int32
```

See also: [What's the meaning of the new tilde token ~ in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70888240/whats-the-meaning-of-the-new-tilde-token-in-go)

`constraints.Integer` also works, because that is defined as:

```
type Integer interface {
    Signed | Unsigned
}
```

https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/constraints#Integer

which is defined as:

```
type Signed interface {
    ~int | ~int8 | ~int16 | ~int32 | ~int64
}

type Unsigned interface {
    ~uint | ~uint8 | ~uint16 | ~uint32 | ~uint64 | ~uintptr
}
```

So that gives you all types that have any of the integer types as the underlying types.

If you're only interested in types that have `int32` as their underlying type, you should use `~int32`.